# Invalid OAUTH access token, when using an application access token, Android

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, access-token

As the title says, when I try to request to get the friends list with the field installed:

```
"me/friends?Fields=installed&access_token=..."
```

I get the following error in my logcat:

```
"Invalid OAuth access token"
```

When looking on the facebook api I see that installed needs to take an application access token.  So I generated the application access token using the appId and app Secret using:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET

Below is the code:

```
try {

 JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me/friends?fields=installed&access_token=..."));

  Log.d("json Response", obj.toString());
  JSONArray array = obj.optJSONArray("data");
  if (array != null) {
                      for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        //  String name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

                          String id = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                          Log.d("Friends: ",id);
                      }
                  } 
  }catch (Exception e){
    Log.d("Friends:", e.getMessage());
  }
```

Any one any ideas why its doing this I have been searching for ages.

Cheers

Comment: Can you post some codes.

Comment: Ye, I'll just have to change computers.  Will edit my original post

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting after authentication is App Access Token.

Quoting : `Authenticating as an App allows you to obtain an access token which allows you to make request to the Facebook API on behalf of an App rather than a User. This is useful, for example to modify the parameters of your App, create and manage test users, or read your application's insights for example. App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on behalf of a user who has granted a publishing permission to your application`

from [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/).

What you need for your case is an user access token. Refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).
A user needs to authenticate and grant access to your app for you have access to his friends list.

**EDIT**

For checking for a single user the url is 
https://graph.facebook.com/{uid}?fields=installed&access_token=< ACCESS_TOKEN >

You are trying to get user friend list and then check if the app is installed. I don't think getting user friend list is possible without user access token.

**EDIT 2**

Assuming from your comment that you have the list of frind's. Then you need not call for each user instead you can use FQL.

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid,is_app_user from user where uid IN (uid1,uid2)`

And if you have the user access token then you can directly do.

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid,is_app_user from user where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I got it working this way, but when going through my friend list which is around 400 people one at a time it was really slow, and comparing this to some people who will have friends list of 1000 it will be too slow.  So was wondering if you can get it to do the whole friend list in one go.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Don’t request /**me**/*friends* – because with an app access token the API won’t know who „me” is supposed to be – request /**userid**/*friends* instead.</del>

Sorry, I was wrong before – the way to go is with an **user access token**, and just setting the request up against /me/friends…

Comment: When I try using facebook.getAccessToken() I get an error saying that im using a malformed access token

Comment: @PhilDarnell, same problem with me, now, have you fix that ?

Comment: it seems like some weird bug; when using (otherparams)&access_token=(facebook.getAccessToken()) it doesn't work, however when I put the access_token in the front of the url ?access_token=(facebook.getAccessToken())&(otherparams) it does work.