# Instagram Api Token Error While Getting Username With Tagging

Tags: api, asp.net-core, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get the username of the owner of the picture I'm tagged in. However, when I try to go to my request url, taking error below. Researched about this case but couldn't find something useful about this situation.

{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 190,
"fbtrace_id": "ALI1tNJ_alXBJmnJWK-w0vq"
}
}

```
`

By the way when I try to get my profile media's and other fields, having no trouble about that. Here's my source codes:
```

```
 public class SocialFeedService
    {
        private readonly string instagramBaseAPIUrl = "https://graph.instagram.com/";
        private readonly string facebookBaseAPIUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/";

        public string GetInstagramContents(string userToken)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    string mediaUrl = $"me/media?fields=id,tags,mentions,username,timestamp,caption,media_url,media_type,permalink&access_token={userToken}";
                    string tagUrl = $"me/tags?fields=id,username&access_token={userToken}";

                    string fullMediaUrl = $"{this.instagramBaseAPIUrl}{mediaUrl}";
                    string fullTagUrl = $"{this.facebookBaseAPIUrl}{tagUrl}";

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var response = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(fullTagUrl)).Result;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                    {
                        var result = response;
                        return result;
                    }

                    return string.Empty;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

```
And here is my controller :
```

```
 public class XControllers : ControllerBase
    {
        IConfiguration configuration;

        public XControllers(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }
       

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            string token = @"IG...";

            var service = new SocialFeedService();
            string result = service.GetInstagramContents(token);


            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
```

```
Thanks in advance.




Just trying to take tagged media owner's username.
```

Comment: Make sure you use user access token, refer to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow). A user needs to authenticate and grant access to your app for you have access to his friends list. [Subir Kumar Sao's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11101531/18789859) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why you receive an `invalid token` error for OAuth. I would recommend ruling out a few of the following:

- `access_token` wasn't properly passed in the Authorization header
- An invalid `access_token` was used (included a typo, invalid string, etc.)
- The `access_token` was expired (typically lasts for 1 hour)

You might also find this guide on [OAuth Troubleshooting tips](https://developers.miro.com/docs/troubleshooting-oauth20) helpful.